# Как обращаться к QStandardItemModel в потоке (QThread)?

Tags: c++, qt, потоки-данных

Мне надо обрабатывать отображение миниатюр фотографий в отдельном потоке, иначе код очень долго обрабатывается. У меня есть в основном классе class MainWindow модель и переменная:

mainwindow.h

```
public:
    static QStandardItemModel * model = new QStandardItemModel;
    static QStandardItem *item_one;
    static int rowTableDisk = 0;
```

Я создаю поток для добавления миниатюр так:

threadsminiature.h

```
    #ifndef THREADSMINIATURE_H
    #define THREADSMINIATURE_H

    #include <QThread>
    #include <QImageReader>
    #include <mainwindow.h>

    class ThreadsMiniature : public QThread
    {
    public:
        explicit ThreadsMiniature(QString threadName, QString Path);

        void run();
        QString _Path;

    private:
        QString name;   // Имя потока
    };

    #endif // THREADSMINIATURE_H
```

threadsminiature.cpp

```
#include "threadsminiature.h"
ThreadsMiniature::ThreadsMiniature(QString threadName, QString Path) :
    name(threadName),
    _Path(Path)
{

}

void ThreadsMiniature::run()
{
    int icoWidth    = 200;
    int icoHeight    = 200;

    QImageReader imageReader(_Path);

    QSize size;
    int image_width;
    int image_height;

    if (imageReader.supportsOption(QImageIOHandler::Size))
    {
        size = imageReader.size();
        image_width = size.width();
        image_height = size.height();
    }

    double ratio = (double)image_width / (double)image_height;
    if (ratio >= 1)
    {
        image_width = icoWidth;
        image_height = image_width / ratio;
    } else {
        image_height = icoHeight;
        image_width = image_height * ratio;
    }

    imageReader.setScaledSize(QSize(image_width, image_height));

    //QImage image = imageReader.read();

    MainWindow::item_one = new QStandardItem();
    MainWindow::item_one->setData(QVariant(QPixmap::fromImage(imageReader.read())), Qt::DecorationRole);
    MainWindow::model->setItem(MainWindow::rowTableDisk, 2, MainWindow::item_one);
}
```

В основном коде заполняю QTableView так :

mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::TableListFiles(QStringList imagePathListCopy, QString DeviceFolder) {

    if (!DeviceFolder.isEmpty()) {
        //Заголовки столбцов
        QStringList horizontalHeader;
        horizontalHeader.append("Отметь, что перенести");
        horizontalHeader.append("Кликабельные ссылки на изображения");
        horizontalHeader.append("Папка в которую будет скопирован файл");
        model->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horizontalHeader);
        for(int i=0; i<imagePathListCopy.count(); i++) {


            if(rowTableDisk == 0) {

                item_one = new QStandardItem("Выбрать/Убрать всё");
                model->setItem(rowTableDisk, 1, item_one);
                rowTableDisk++;
                //item_one = new QStandardItem("<a href=\""+imagePathListCopy.at(i)+"\">"+QFileInfo(imagePathListCopy.at(i)).fileName()+"</a>");
                item_one = new QStandardItem(imagePathListCopy.at(i));
                model->setItem(rowTableDisk, 1, item_one);

                QImage image(imagePathListCopy.at(i));
                item_one = new QStandardItem();
                item_one->setData(QVariant(QPixmap::fromImage(image)), Qt::DecorationRole);
                model->setItem(rowTableDisk, 2, item_one);

                item_one = new QStandardItem(DeviceFolder);
                model->setItem(rowTableDisk, 3, item_one);
            } else {
                //item_one = new QStandardItem("<a href=\""+imagePathListCopy.at(i)+"\">"+QFileInfo(imagePathListCopy.at(i)).fileName()+"</a>");
                item_one = new QStandardItem(imagePathListCopy.at(i));
                model->setItem(rowTableDisk, 1, item_one);


                ThreadsMiniature *threadB = new ThreadsMiniature(QString("thread_%1").arg(i),imagePathListCopy.at(i));
                threadB->start();
                //QImage image(imagePathListCopy.at(i));

                item_one = new QStandardItem(DeviceFolder);
                model->setItem(rowTableDisk, 3, item_one);
            }
            rowTableDisk++;
        }
    } else {
        //Заголовки столбцов
        QStringList horizontalHeader;
        horizontalHeader.append("Отметь, что перенести");
        horizontalHeader.append("Кликабельные ссылки на изображения");
        model->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horizontalHeader);
        int rowTableDisk = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<imagePathListCopy.count();i++) {
            if(rowTableDisk == 0) {
                item_one = new QStandardItem("Выбрать/Убрать всё");
                model->setItem(rowTableDisk, 1, item_one);
                rowTableDisk++;
                //item_one = new QStandardItem("<a href=\""+imagePathListCopy.at(i)+"\">"+QFileInfo(imagePathListCopy.at(i)).fileName()+"</a>");
                item_one = new QStandardItem(imagePathListCopy.at(i));
                model->setItem(rowTableDisk, 1, item_one);
            } else {
                //item_one = new QStandardItem("<a href=\""+imagePathListCopy.at(i)+"\">"+QFileInfo(imagePathListCopy.at(i)).fileName()+"</a>");
                item_one = new QStandardItem(imagePathListCopy.at(i));
                model->setItem(rowTableDisk, 1, item_one);
            }
            rowTableDisk++;
        }
    }
    CheckBoxDelegate *CheckBoxD = new CheckBoxDelegate(this);
    HrefDelegate *HrefD = new HrefDelegate(this);
    TableDisk->setModel(model);
    TableDisk->setItemDelegateForColumn(0, CheckBoxD);
    TableDisk->setItemDelegateForColumn(1, HrefD);
    TableDisk->setColumnWidth(0,150);
    TableDisk->setColumnWidth(1,600);
    TableDisk->setColumnWidth(2,300);
}
```

Но ошибки :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как использовать в потоке `static QStandardItemModel * model = new QStandardItemModel;` и `static int rowTableDisk = 0;` ?

Comment: Перенесите инициализацию в в cpp файл, или сделайте поля `model` и `rowTableDisk` константными. Это вольный перевод того что говорит вам  компилятор.

Answer (score 1):

Не поместилось в комментарий, оставлю как ответ:

C потоками лучше так не работать.

Есть как минимум `QThreadPool`, а также `Qt Concurrent` - я правда в нём не разбираюсь, цитата из документации - `The QtConcurrent namespace provides high-level APIs that make it possible to write multi-threaded programs without using low-level threading primitives such as mutexes, read-write locks, wait conditions, or semaphores.`

Наследоваться от QThread не рекомендуется - [Правильное использование QThread](https://habr.com/post/150274/). 
Если вкратце - QThread в первую очередь нужен чтобы запустить QEventLoop в другом потоке и иметь возможность слать сигналы в этот поток и принимать их оттуда. Подробнее - прочитайте статью по [ссылке](https://habr.com/post/150274/) на хабре.

Оригинальные статьи:

[youre-doing-it-wrong QThread](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/)

[how to realy use qthreads](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/)

*** UPD. ***

Прочитал исходники.

У вас получается что в цикле будет создано несколько потоков, и каждый из них будет обращаться к одному и тому же статическому элементу (`item_one`) ?

Без синхронизации ?

*** UPD 2. Пример. ***

Я сделал предположение о том что Вам требуется, и сделал пример.

Пример грузит из некоторой папки все картинки форматов `jpg/png` в таблицу с двумя столбцами - имя картинки и preview. Код получения preview скопировал из вашего метода `run` в потоке

Класс `ImageLoader` - наследник `QObject`(чтобы умел слать сигнал) и `QRunnable` (чтобы можно было добавлять в QThreadPool).

Я не уверен что так правильно, потому-что метода `moveToThread` `QThreadPool` скорей всего не вызывает, так как на вход ожидает обычный `QRunnable` интерфейс, но всё же это лучше чем наследоваться от `QThread`.

```
#ifndef IMAGELOADER_H
#define IMAGELOADER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QRunnable>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QImage>

class ImageLoader: public QObject, public QRunnable
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ImageLoader(const QFileInfo& img, QObject* parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~ImageLoader(){
        m_img = nullptr;    //не удаляем - удалить обязан тот кто будет обрабатывать сигнал imgReady
    }
    virtual void run() override;
signals:
    void imgReady(const QFileInfo& file, QImage* img);
private:
    QFileInfo m_imgFile;
    QImage*   m_img;
};

#endif // IMAGELOADER_H


#include "imageloader.h"

#include <QImageReader>
#include <QDebug>

ImageLoader::ImageLoader(const QFileInfo &img, QObject *parent):
    QObject(parent),
    m_imgFile{img},
    m_img{nullptr}
{
    setAutoDelete(true);
}

void ImageLoader::run()
{
    if (!m_imgFile.exists()){
        qDebug() << __FUNCTION__ << "file" << m_imgFile.absoluteFilePath() << "do not exists";
        return;
    }
    int icoWidth    = 200;
    int icoHeight    = 200;

    QImageReader imageReader(m_imgFile.absoluteFilePath());

    QSize size;
    int image_width;
    int image_height;

    if (imageReader.supportsOption(QImageIOHandler::Size))
    {
        size = imageReader.size();
        image_width = size.width();
        image_height = size.height();
    }else{
        qCritical() << "QImageReader don support option QImageIOHandler::Size";
        return;
    }

    double ratio = (double)image_width / (double)image_height;
    if (ratio >= 1)
    {
        image_width = icoWidth;
        image_height = image_width / ratio;
    } else {
        image_height = icoHeight;
        image_width = image_height * ratio;
    }

    imageReader.setScaledSize(QSize(image_width, image_height));

    m_img = new QImage();
    if (imageReader.read(m_img)){
        emit imgReady(m_imgFile, m_img);
    }else{
        qWarning() << "can't read image" << m_imgFile.fileName() << imageReader.errorString();
        delete m_img;
    }
}
```

MainWindow

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDir>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QFileInfo>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_m_selectDirBtn_clicked();
    void onImgReady(const QFileInfo& file, QImage* img);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QDir           m_imgDir;
    QStandardItemModel* m_imgModel;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThreadPool>
#include <QMutexLocker>

#include "imageloader.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    m_imgDir{"", "*.jpg; *.png", QDir::Name | QDir::IgnoreCase, QDir::Files},
    m_imgModel{}
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    m_imgModel = new QStandardItemModel(0, 2, this);
    ui->m_imageTableView->setModel(m_imgModel);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_m_selectDirBtn_clicked()
{
    QString dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this);
    qDebug() << dir;
    if (dir.isEmpty()){
        qWarning() << "Пользователь отменил выбор директории";
    }else{
        m_imgDir.setPath(dir);
        qDebug() << m_imgDir.entryList();
        m_imgModel->clear();
        for (const auto& img: m_imgDir.entryList()){
            ImageLoader* imgLoader = new ImageLoader(QFileInfo(m_imgDir.filePath(img)));
            connect(imgLoader, SIGNAL(imgReady(QFileInfo,QImage*)),
                    this, SLOT(onImgReady(QFileInfo,QImage*)),
                    Qt::QueuedConnection);
            QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(imgLoader);
        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::onImgReady(const QFileInfo &file, QImage *img)
{

    if (img){
        QStandardItem* imgItem = new QStandardItem();
        imgItem->setData(QVariant(QPixmap::fromImage(*img)), Qt::DecorationRole);
        m_imgModel->appendRow({new QStandardItem(file.fileName()),
                               imgItem});
        ui->m_imageTableView->resizeRowToContents(m_imgModel->rowCount()-1);
        ui->m_imageTableView->resizeColumnsToContents();
        qInfo() << "img loaded" << "threads count:" << QThreadPool::globalInstance()->activeThreadCount();
    }
    if (img){
        delete img;
    }
}
```

На форме одна кнопка для выбора директории и TableView для отображения модели:

mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>489</width>
    <height>256</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>640</width>
    <height>480</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Потоки</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
    <item>
     <widget class="QTableView" name="m_imageTableView"/>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="m_selectDirBtn">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Выбрать директорию</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>489</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Как выглядит:

[image: Изображения одинаковых размеров]
[image: Изображения разных размров]

Вывод в консоль:

```
"C:/Users/User/Pictures"
("2017-07-17_01.13.04.png", "galio.jpg", "galio.under.lol.png", "galio_and_text.png", "galio_w320.png", "lol.jpg", "lol.png", "LoL_Bug.1.png", "LoL_Bug.2.png", "LoL_Bug.3.png", "LoL_Bug.png", "photo_2018-03-08_23-37-28.jpg", "photo_2018-03-08_23-37-45.jpg", "photo_2018-03-08_23-37-51.jpg", "photo_2018-03-08_23-37-54.jpg", "photo_2018-03-08_23-37-57.jpg", "photo_2018-03-08_23-38-00.jpg", "photo_2018-03-08_23-38-02.jpg", "photo_2018-03-08_23-38-05.jpg", "photo_2018-03-08_23-38-08.jpg", "twitch.png", "Безымянный.png", "Снимок.PNG")
img loaded threads count: 4
img loaded threads count: 4
img loaded threads count: 4
img loaded threads count: 4
img loaded threads count: 4
img loaded threads count: 4
img loaded threads count: 4
img loaded threads count: 2
img loaded threads count: 2
img loaded threads count: 1
img loaded threads count: 1
img loaded threads count: 1
img loaded threads count: 1
img loaded threads count: 1
img loaded threads count: 1
img loaded threads count: 1
img loaded threads count: 1
img loaded threads count: 1
img loaded threads count: 1
img loaded threads count: 1
img loaded threads count: 1
img loaded threads count: 1
img loaded threads count: 0
```

Как видим, было задействовано до 4 потоков.

Чуть не забыл - в main.cpp пришлось зарегистрировать QFileInfo, чтобы слать его в сигнале в качестве параметра:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFileInfo>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    qRegisterMetaType<QFileInfo>("QFileInfo");
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Я видел эти статьи. Сделал по уроку:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PR6wVy7Et1A&t=262s только как передать два значение в emit drowMiniature(imageReader.read()); Не понял. Думал Вектором но у QVector<QImage> MiniatureVector; нет SetObjectName

Comment: Иначе картинки не в то место добавляются

Comment: Наличие этого урока на ютубе, как и прочих уроков, не делает его корректным. Там впустую используется mutex, сигналы из потока посылаются без явного указания Qt::QueuedConnection, и прочее прочее прочее, в комментариях к видео есть замечания от пользователей. Да и пример там странный, проще было использовать QTimer для того что показано в видео

Comment: Я не понимаю что вы хотите сделать, можете привести полный (минимальный и достаточный) пример ?

Comment: Я уже вынес в поток то что хотел. Хотя скорей всего неправильно . Но на данном этапе все быстро работает и меня это устраивает. А я хотел вынести в отдельный поток отображение миниатюр фотографий. Сейчас мне очень надо с другим вопросом разобраться https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/848477/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BA-qtabelview-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0 Напишу свой готовый вариант тут еще.

Comment: Я написал то что у меня получилось.

Comment: Поставил +1 вашему ответу. Но не буду его отмечать как решение, так как это не конкретное решение(нет кода). Мой ответ более конкретный.

Comment: Спасибо мне надо проверить - это . Я позже вернусь к этому вопросу.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно не корректный код, но рабочий и быстрый :

threadsminiature.h

```
#ifndef THREADSMINIATURE_H
#define THREADSMINIATURE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <QImageReader>
#include <QVector>

class ThreadsMiniature : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ThreadsMiniature(QObject *parent=0, QString Path="", int rowTableDisk = 0);

    void run();
    QString _Path;
    int _rowTableDisk;
    //QList<QImage> MiniatureList;

signals:
    //QImage drowMiniature(QImage image) {return image;}
    void drowMiniature(QImage);
private:
    QString name;   // Имя потока
};

#endif // THREADSMINIATURE_H
```

Более двух значений в функцию MainWindow::Miniature, можно передать с помощью

```
QImage image = imageReader.read();
image.setText("row", QString("%1").arg(_rowTableDisk));
```

Так как QVector< QImage > не имеет метода SetObjectName:

threadsminiature.cpp

```
#include "threadsminiature.h"
#include <QtCore>

ThreadsMiniature::ThreadsMiniature(QObject *parent, QString Path, int rowTableDisk) :
    QThread(parent),
    _Path(Path),
    _rowTableDisk(rowTableDisk)
{

}

void ThreadsMiniature::run()
{
    int icoWidth    = 200;
    int icoHeight    = 200;

    QImageReader imageReader(_Path);

    QSize size;
    int image_width;
    int image_height;

    if (imageReader.supportsOption(QImageIOHandler::Size))
    {
        size = imageReader.size();
        image_width = size.width();
        image_height = size.height();
    }

    double ratio = (double)image_width / (double)image_height;
    if (ratio >= 1)
    {
        image_width = icoWidth;
        image_height = image_width / ratio;
    } else {
        image_height = icoHeight;
        image_width = image_height * ratio;
    }

    imageReader.setScaledSize(QSize(image_width, image_height));

    QImage image = imageReader.read();
    image.setText("row", QString("%1").arg(_rowTableDisk));
    emit drowMiniature(image);

}
```

Обойти обращение к модели(QStandardItemModel), в потоке можно вынеся в отделенную функцию MainWindow::Miniature обращение к этой модели.

mainwindow.cpp

```
.....
     //item_one = new QStandardItem("<a href=\""+imagePathListCopy.at(i)+"\">"+QFileInfo(imagePathListCopy.at(i)).fileName()+"</a>");
     item_one = new QStandardItem(imagePathListCopy.at(i));
                model->setItem(rowTableDisk, 1, item_one);

     ThreadsMiniature *threadB = new ThreadsMiniature(this,imagePathListCopy.at(i),rowTableDisk);
     connect(threadB, SIGNAL(drowMiniature(QImage)),this,SLOT(Miniature(QImage)));
      threadB->start();

      item_one = new QStandardItem(DeviceFolder);
                model->setItem(rowTableDisk, 3, item_one);
....

void MainWindow::Miniature (QImage image) {
        QString rowString = image.text("row");
        qDebug()<<rowString;
        int rowTable = rowString.toInt();
        item_one = new QStandardItem();
        item_one->setData(QVariant(QPixmap::fromImage(image)), Qt::DecorationRole);//DecorationRole
        model->setItem(rowTable, 2, item_one);
        //rowMiniature++;
}
```